# Using filterdiff to exclude a diff

Tags: patch

I have a big patch (`foo`), consisting of diffs from many files. I want to exclude a specific diff (corresponding to a single file) from this patch. The beginning of this diff looks like this:

```
diff --git a/business/smyt/scans/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf b/business/smyt/scans/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf
new file mode 100644
index e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391..4d5780b2dc843386b9641f4cb42a4ba4a7996cae
GIT binary patch
literal 106388
```

I'm trying the following command. Filterdiff is available on Debian, at least, in the `patchutils` package.

```
filterdiff --exclude='*/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf' foo > newfoo
```

but it returns the same file. This is probably user error. The man page (`man filterdiff`) says:

```
-x PATTERN, --exclude=PATTERN
       Exclude files matching PATTERN. All other lines in the input are displayed.
```

This probably requires usage of regular expressions, something which I have never been comfortable with.

Another method of doing this would also be fine. I could manually edit the patch as a last resort, but automated methods are generally better.

Comment: I tried `filterdiff --exclude='.*/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf' foo > newfoo`. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that filterdiff doesn't know how to handle the git option as your PATTERN seems ok:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ seq 5 > a/file1
$ rm file1 
rm: remove regular file ‘file1’? y
$ seq 5 > b/file2
$ seq 4 > b/file1
$ seq 4 > a/file2
$ diff -r -u a b
diff -r -u a/file1 b/file1
--- a/file1 2015-03-07 09:24:15.548744157 +0100
+++ b/file1 2015-03-07 09:24:37.804744069 +0100
@@ -2,4 +2,3 @@
 2
 3
 4
-5
diff -r -u a/file2 b/file2
--- a/file2 2015-03-07 09:24:42.448744051 +0100
+++ b/file2 2015-03-07 09:24:30.684744097 +0100
@@ -2,3 +2,4 @@
 2
 3
 4
+5
$ diff -r -u a b > my.patch
$ wc my.patch
 16  46 302 my.patch
$ filterdiff --exclude='*/file2' my.patch | wc
      9      28     178
$ filterdiff --exclude='*/file2' my.patch 
diff -r -u a/file1 b/file1
--- a/file1 2015-03-07 09:24:15.548744157 +0100
+++ b/file1 2015-03-07 09:24:37.804744069 +0100
@@ -2,4 +2,3 @@
 2
 3
 4
-5
diff -r -u a/file2 b/file2
```

Comment: There is also the depth issue. There is a `p` flag for handling this, like with patch, but again I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't think that patch depth is relevant here. Have you tried cut-and-pasting the full name?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: `filterdiff --exclude='a/business/smyt/scans/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf' foo` instead of using the `*`

Comment: `filterdiff --exclude='a/business/smyt/scans/deboo.2015.02.11.pdf' foo` doesn't work either.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is with `GIT binary patch` and other git-specific syntax that filterdiff does not understand. Non binary patches were filtered, binary patches were not. Instead try using `--exclude` option of `git apply`.